# java.AWT - setSize() method

Tags: java, awt

I am facing an issue using setSize() method in  the below program.

> Error : The method setSize(int,int) is not defined for the type frame.

When I see Java API, "Class Frame" has this Method inherited from class 
java.awt.Window. As i have instantiated the Frame class, this object should have setSize() method  as Frame is derived class of Window. 
Why am I getting this error then? How can a derived class doesnt contain its superclass method?

```
public class AwtPrac{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame fm = new Frame("Java Programm");
    Button b= new Button ("Click Here");
    fm.add(b);
    fm.setVisible(true);
    fm.SetSize(300,300);
    fm.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: What JDK version are you using?

Comment: java version 1.8.0_74

Comment: `SetSize` <- Java is case sensitve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this code

```
   import java.awt.Frame;

  public class AwtPrac  {

private static  void init(){
    Frame fm = new Frame("Java Programm");
   fm.setTitle("AwtPrac");
   fm.setSize(300,300);
    fm.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    init();
}

}
```

Comment: Why is my query not working?As i have instantiated the Frame class, this object should have setSize() method as Frame is derived class of Window. Why am I getting this error then? How can a derived class doesnt contain its superclass method?

Comment: you write : fm.SetSize() instead of fm.setSize(). The method start with the first letter to lower case...

Comment: you could put the question resolved ? you have to press the arrow . thank you